# PostgreSQL: Foreign key to a table with SCD 2

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, scd

Using a foreign key to connect two simple tables is straight forward in PostgreSQL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE location (
    id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE event (
    id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
    location_id UUID,
    title TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY(location_id) REFERENCES location(id)
);

INSERT INTO location VALUES ('41af871f-a939-46d1-8cac-dd8489ca3248', 'Jupiter');
INSERT INTO event VALUES ('56ab1bf0-36bc-4380-a9d2-fccb88f5ca03', '41af871f-a939-46d1-8cac-dd8489ca3248', 'Success');
-- the next insert statement is supposed to fail
INSERT INTO event VALUES ('da5ecc5f-d63f-4803-883f-70cda9da7583', '529d1030-0db1-4299-8557-055471820b66', 'Failure');
```

The last statement fails as expected, since there is no location with `id` =
`529d1030-0db1-4299-8557-055471820b66`

Now my actual `location` table is slightly more complex, because it uses
[SCD Type 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension#Type_2:_add_new_row)
with date columns:

```sql
CREATE TABLE location (
    id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT
    checkin TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    checkout TIMESTAMP, -- is null for the latest/current version
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "unique_location" ON location (id, (checkout IS NULL)) WHERE checkout IS NULL;
```

The `location` table can now contain multiple versions of a location with a
certain id. Only 0 or 1 versions are valid for a given time. Outdated versions
have a timerange in the `checkin` and`checkout` fields, while the `checkout`
field of the latest or current version is set to `NULL`.

Now I want to have a foreign key in the `event` table, that refers to the current
version of a location. A bit like the following (non-working) pseudocode:

```sql
CREATE TABLE event (
    -- field definitions
    FOREIGN KEY(location_id) REFERENCES location(id) WHERE location(checkout) IS NULL
);
```

Is this possible somehow and how?

Comment: 1) You are using  `timestamp` not  `date` columns. FYI, save future headaches and use `timestamptz` instead. 2) I don't understand how *The location table can now contain multiple versions of a location with a certain id.* works when `id` is a PK?

Comment: 2) `id` is not a PK. The combination of `id` and `checkout` is unique and an index is created on these fields.

Comment: 1) timestamp always contains UTC datetime, not local datetime. @AdrianKlaver Do you think it is better to use `TIMESTAMPTZ` in this case as well?

Comment: 1) `id UUID PRIMARY KEY,` says it is a PK. Therefore `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "unique_location" ON location (id, (checkout IS NULL) ...` will not do what you think it is. 2) `timestamptz` values are stored as UTC. Then you know for certain.

Comment: PostgreSQL requires that foreign key contraints reference unique keys. There are other database platforms that support temporal referential integrity. Tiggers and stored procedures can be used to implement the type of behavior you've described; however, it's not a trivial exercise, offers ample opportunities to introduce defects, and can add significant complexity to even relatively simple queries. PostgreSQL has some features, such as the `tsrange` data type and exclusion constraints using `GIST` indexes, that facilitate handling temporal constraints.